# Magento Theme CSS not Loading

Tags: php, css, magento

I installed Magento Gala Bigshop theme here: http://www.mobilsokak.com

When I make a change on theme (Gala Bigshop) settings on admin panel, site's CSS starts to not loading. You can see it on http://www.mobilsokak.com now.

Theme's original look: _store=default">http://demo.galathemes.com/gala-bigshop/index.php/?_store=default

Should I do something after theme setting update?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Log into your Magento Admin Panel and navigate to System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer.
Under Javascript Settings and CSS Settings, set Merge JavaScript Files and Merge CSS Files to Yes.
Now save config.
Check if the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

try `recaching` your `magento cache`.. from your `mangento admin`..

`admin->system->cache management`.. and select all and select `refresh` from rightside dropdown..

also push `flush javascript/css cache` button from bottom...

let me know if you want further guidance..

Comment: Hello, I made this but there is nothing to change.

Comment: how you are applying your theme? from `system->design` ??
please select store as `main website`....

Comment: ok than try this.. go to `system->configuration->design`  and in that you will see `templates and Skin (Images / CSS)`, put your theme name there in both fields.. and `refresh the cache` .. and check what happens

Comment: ohh. have you cleared your `browser cache`?? clear it using `ctrl+shift+delete`... and check again

Answer (score 0):

*Have you changed the colors in the theme through backend?*
Because its applying **FFFFFF** color everywhere in the site which is giving error as ***there is no # applied infront of FFFFFF*** if you check in debugger.
Also there is a missing css file at /skin/frontend/default/galabigshop/em_blog/css/styles.css.
Check if adding this file could make any change and also check colors in backend.
You can get the css if not there from

> http://demo.galathemes.com/gala-bigshop/skin/frontend/default/galabigshop/em_blog/css/styles.css

Comment: I had the same issue. There was no # applied in front of any of the colours in the theme settings. Turned out to be Phxsolution_Formbuilder plugin on Magento CE 1.9.x. I had to disable the plugin from /app/etc/modules/Phxsolution_Formbuilder.xml